# reactJS dynamic drop down populated with map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a simple drop down with numbers from 1 to 100.  I create an object with an array as its only element.  I populate each array element with a value and then I try to map the object to generate the drop down items.  This is the code I am executing:

```
renderPercent = () => {
    let obj = {
        array: []
    };
    for (var l=0;l<100;l++){
        obj.array[l] = l+1;
    }
    console.log("obj: ", obj);
    let optionItems = obj.array.map((item) =>
        <option key={item}>{item}</option>
    );
    return (
        <div>                
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-9 text-left">
                    <label>Select the percent to transfer</label>
                </div>
                <div className="col-2 text-left">
                    <select>
                        {optionItems}
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div className="col-1 text-left">
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I modified the optionItems map function as suggested.  This is what now is generated when this screen is rendered:

[image]

As you can see, the map function is now populating my drop down.  However, the dropdown goes below the end of the device.  Is this just something that is a bug when viewing in Chrome with developer tools?  And the other thing I noticed is that the numbers in the dropdown are a larger font than the reset of the page.  Before I click on the dropdown arrow, the value 1 shows in the drowdown and that is the correct size, but as soon as I expand the drop down, the numbers seem much larger.  Why would that be?

Again, thanks to the stackoverflow community!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`obj` is an object, it doesn't have a `map` function. Whereas `obj.array` is a list that have a `map` function.

The following code

```
let optionItems = obj.map((item) =>
        <option key={item.array}>{item.array}</option>
    );
```

should be

```
let optionItems = obj.array.map((item) =>
        <option key={item}>{item}</option>
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to map on an object, not an array, modify your code as so:

```
obj.map((item) =>
```

should be

```
obj["array"].map((item) =>
```

You can see that in your console.log. It says **{** array: **[**....

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
{Array.from(Array(100), (e, i) => {
    return <option value={i+1}>{i+1}</option>
   }
 )}
```

> "i" will contain a value from 0 to 100 that's why I make it "i+1"

Answer (score 0):

You are doing .map on object but not on array. Try with . notation

```
let optionItems = obj.array.map((item) =>
   <option key={item.array}>{item.array}</option>
);
```

complete code

```
renderPercent = () => {
    let obj = {
        array: []
    };
    for (var l=0;l<100;l++){
        obj.array[l] = l+1;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <select>
                {obj.array.length > 0 && obj.array.map((item) =>
                    <option key={item.array}>{item.array}</option>
                 )}
            </select>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some like this:

```
var percentArray = [];

for (var l=0;l<100;l++){
    percentArray.push(l);
}

let optionItems= percentArray.map(x => `<option key=${x}>${x}</option>`);

...

    return (
        <div>
            <select>
                {optionItems}
            </select>
        </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

**I am using the below code for achieving the dropdown functionality using "selectArry"**.

```
const selectArry = [
{
   Key: "es",
   Value: "Espresso",
},
{
   Key: "ri",
   Value: "Ristretto",
},
{
   Key: "lb",
   Value: "Long Black",
},{
   Key: "mm",
   Value: "Mezzo Mezzo",
},{
   Key: "c",
   Value: "Cappuccino",
}]

<select name="coffee" defaultValue="">
  {props.selectArry && props.selectArry?.data.map((cItem) =>
      <option key={cItem.Value}>{cItem.Value}</option>
   )}
</select>
```